# Let $M$ be a connected manifold. Can we find a surjective submersion $q:S \rightarrow M$ with $S$ connected and with the property that $\pi_2(S)=0$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

We can also ask the same question for higher homotopy groups, the existence of the universal cover tells us that the answer is positive for the fundamental group.

Comment: Are you asking for this exact condition for a reason ? Or would you just like to know if there is a generalization of universal covers for higher homotopy groups ? If so, then yes, and the interesting property is that for any space $X$ there is a space $X_n$ and a map $p_n:X_n \to X$ such that $\pi_k(X_n)=0$ if $k\leq n$, and $\pi_k(p_n)$ is an isomorphism for $k> n$. This space is even unique in some sense. For your precise question I don't know but I would be surprised (spaces obtained by removing higher homotopy groups often have cohomology in unbounded degrees so often can't be manifolds).

Comment: I believe the answer is yes if $\pi_2(M)$ is finitely generated.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese:  I agree if $\pi_2(M)$ is finitely generated a free.  Then one can even keep all the higher homotopy groups the same by using a torus bundle.  But I don't know what to do with torsion in $\pi_2(M)$.  For example, for the Wu manifold $SU(3)/SO(3)$, is there such an $S$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Well, $S = SU(3)$ suffices for that example, but you're right, the argument I had in mind needed $\pi_2$ to be free abelian of finite rank.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese:  Wow.  I've been trying to prove no such $S$ exists for the Wu manifold for several minutes, and you provide the most obvious counterexample.  I'm a bit ashamed!  Thanks for pointing that out ;-)